# Average Treemap values, based on Keys

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I have a treemap that stores keys and values something like this:

```
key    value
ko4    23
ko4    53
ko4    34
po1    100
po1    8
po1    90
po3    99
po3    234
po3    34
```

I want to take the average of every key (and eventually print them to a new file). So I would do the averages and put them in another map, HashMap for this one because I will need to sort by values before I print them to a new file. The new map would look something like this:

```
Key    Value
ko4   36.6
po1   66
po3   122.3
```

I am trying to get this to work, but I am having a hard time. Maybe I am overcomplicating things. Here is what I have.

```
      Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
      int sum = 0;
      int average;
      int number = 1;
      map.put(key, value); //I actually read in a file to do this, but so it is reproducible I have it like this, people can put in whatever they please
      String lastkey = map.key(0);//I don't know if I can get key somehow

      for (int i = 0;i < map.size();i++){ //for the size of the map
         thiskey = map.key(i);
         if (thiskey.equals(lastkey)){ //if it is the same key as the last one
            if (i == 0){
               sum = map.get(i);
            }else{
              sum = sum + map.get(i); //add the values
              number++;
            }
         average = sum / number;
         }else{ 
          lastkey = thiskey;
         }
```

I need some help bridging some gaps here. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: First, no `Map` -- including `TreeMap` -- can have multiple values for the same key.  Second, there's no way of looking up the key at a specific index.  Perhaps you're looking for a `Multimap`, or a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.

Comment: Use map.keySet() to get a set of the keys in the map, but like @LouisWasserman says, you can't have identical keys in a map.  You need to change your code around to use a different data structure.  You may want to use a Map to store the running average, but not for the initial dataset.

Comment: `Is there a better way to do this?` I don't think so, you code seems good and readable,

Comment: @ Louis Wasserman i dont agree with this statement that  no Map  can have multiple values for the same key.what if we have HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>? .This has a list of integer values for the same key

Comment: @KaushikSivakumar - That's just one key type (<String, ArrayList<Integer>>).   How will the OP effectively retrieve values from a map with that key type when he/she specified key as a String?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I will look into a multimap

Comment: @Ireeder consider this: ko4    23 ko4    53 ko4    34 (the opt wanted the average)...for this map can be like <ko4,<23,53,34>> .he can traverse the arraylist to get the average.i agree there cannot be multiple identical keys though.//edit:i guess i misunderstood louis comment when i saw your comment now.i understood what he meant

Comment: @KaushikSivakumar How would I add or access values to/in the arraylist? Something like map.get(i).add(value)? I am getting hung up on this idea. Could you show an example?

Comment: @user2076476 couldnt post in comment ,so posted your new question as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//couldnt post this answer in comments as it was too big too be posted in comments but hope it helps you

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    //initialize variables
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> hm=new HashMap();
    ArrayList<Integer> values=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.add(0);
    values.add(1);
    values.add(2);
    hm.put("ko4", values);
    System.out.println(hm.get("ko4").get(0));//prints index 0
    System.out.println(hm.get("ko4").get(1));//prints index 1
    System.out.println(hm.get("ko4").get(2));//prints index 2

}
```